# Cannot use System.out.println();

Tags: java

Please help me. Eclipse said that in the if clause is a mistake. I am not allowed to use Println there and 
if (eingabe=z1)
is also a mistake (eingabe= z1) is red

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Benedikt {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random zufall = new Random ();
        int eingabe;    
        Scanner leser1= new Scanner (System.in);

        int z1;
        z1 = zufall.nextInt(6)+1;

        System.out.println("I have got a number between 1 and 6 in my mind. %n");
        System.out.println("Try to guess it!");

        //Eingabe
        eingabe=leser1.nextInt(eingabe);

        if (eingabe=z1){
            System.out.println("You have found out the number! My number was %d",z1);
        } else if(eingabe > z1){
            System.out.println("My number is smaller than %d", eingabe);
        } else if (eingabe<z1){
            System.out.println("My number is smaller than %d", eingabe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `eingabe=z1` is assignment.

Comment: @GhostCat: there is `main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `println` takes only one argument. You can either use printf (but should append `%n` for the linebreak):

   ```
   System.out.printf("You have found out the number! My number was %d%n", z1);
   ```

   or concatenate the string:

   ```
   System.out.println("You have found out the number! My number was " + z1);
   ```
2. `if (eingabe = z1)` should be `if (eingabe == z1)`. `eingabe = z1` is an assignment and does not return a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to compare(condition in the `if`) equality you must use `==` not `=`(this is for assign a value to variable).

Not `prinln` you need to use [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html):

```
System.out.printf("You have found out the number! My number was %d\n", z1);
```

`println()` does not allow you to provide format specifier within its parenthesis. It is similar to `print()` excepting that `println()` add next line after printing.

`printf()` allows you to write format specifiers like `%d`, `%s`and etc, thus you can use `printf()` anywhere in your code where you have previously been using `print()` or `println()`(with `\n` to get new line).

Comment: @GhostCat: there is main() and I cannot see any problem in my solution

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thanks for your kindness! I have updated my answer.